# Creating a 'view' link in a grid listing that navigates to a detail route such as hero/:id in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

**In my template I am doing the following:**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let h of heroes">
    <td>{{ h.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ h.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ h.description}}</td>
    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I make it so View is a link that navigates to /heroes/:id? I have this setup in my route config. I verified that it works by going to http://localhost:4200/heroes/1

Am I better off using the (click) event and calling a function such as viewHero(id). If I did this I wouldn't be sure how to pass the id. Also, if it can be done directly inside of the html template within the href tag or routerLink I would like to know how to do that too. My main problem seems to be accessing h.id inside of a string such as href="".

**Update:** I got the following to work, but still not happy with it:

```
  <td><a (click)="viewHero(h)">View</a></td>

  viewHero(hero) {
    this.router.navigate(['/heroes', hero.id]);
  }
```

There has to be a way to simply do this inside of the anchor tag directly. I am not getting a pointer finger when hovering the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let h of heroes">
    <td>{{ h.id}}</td>
    <td>{{ h.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ h.description}}</td>
    <td><a routerLink="/heroes/{{h.id}}">View</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Works, thanks. I also noticed that in my case since my listing page is /heroes and my detail page is /heroes/id I am able to simply just put {{h.id}} as the routerLink and it still works!